# Category page layout meta update - add og:image

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, layout-update, open-graph

Can I update layout at category page to add og:image tag?
I need to use special image as og:image, not category image nor thumbnail image.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the following to your local.xml file:

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="head">
       <block type="core/template" name="og" as="og" template="og/category.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

Now you need to create the file under **og/category.phtml** inside you theme **(app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/template/og/category.phtml)** with the following content:

```
<?php $_category = Mage::registry('current_category'); ?>
<?php if ($_category) : ?>
  <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>"/>
  <meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_category->getDescription())?>"/> 
  <meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_category->getName())?>"/>
  <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $_category->getImageUrl()?>"/>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry, I forget to tell that I don't want to use category image as og:image. I need to use different and I wouldn't mind to upload image through ftp and insert url of image by hand.

Comment: That should be easy to change instead of $_category->getImageUrl(); you can add your image URL in category.phtml file

Comment: But in that case I would get same picture for all categories. I need to set unique image for each of course :)

Comment: You can create a category attribute and add your individual image paths in there.

Comment: I created image attribute using code from http://developerafroz.blogspot.cz/2012/01/magento-add-custom-image-attribute-to.html but I don't know which code use insted of $_category->getImageUrl(); Any help please?

Comment: What is the name of the attribute you used? If you have used category_image then it should be $_category->getCategoryImage();

Comment: From the code in the link I thought it is sliderimage so I call it but it doesn't work - $_category->getSliderImage();

Comment: You need to call $_category->getSliderimage() instead of $_category->getSliderImage();